# Proof verification of $x_n = \frac{2-\cos\pi n}{2+\cos \pi n}$ does not have a limit using $\varepsilon$ definition

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

> Let:
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> x_n = \frac{2-\cos\pi n}{2+\cos \pi n} \\
> a = 3
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Prove that $a$ is not the limit of $\{x_n\}$ using $\varepsilon$ definition.

Start with the definition of limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = a \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \{\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb N, \forall n>N:|x_n - a| < \varepsilon \}
$$

Now negate that definition. For the sequence to not have a limit we have the following to be true:

$$
\{\exists \varepsilon >0, \forall N \in \mathbb N, \exists n > N: |x_n - a| \ge \varepsilon\}
$$

Try to find such epsilon. Since $n \in \mathbb N$ we have that for $k\in\mathbb N$:

$$
\begin{equation}
    |x_n| =
    \begin{cases}
      3, & n=2k -1,  \\
      {1\over 3}, & n = 2k
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
$$

Now take for instance $\varepsilon = 1$. With that $\varepsilon$ for any $N$ we may find infinitely many $n$ such that $n > N \ \text{and}\  |x_n -3| \ge 1$. Thus the sequence does not have a limit.

I'm kindly asking to verify two things:

1. The negation of limit definition
2. The proof itself

Btw is it true that any periodic sequence doesn't have a limit?

Thank you!

Comment: $x_n=\frac{1}{3}$ if n=even  , and if n=odd  $x_n=3$

Comment: @Dadrahm right, i've spotted that as well. It should be $3$ instead of $2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the limit relies on finding an arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$ but as small as you would like to, essentialy "reaching" zero thus $x_n \to a$. Since you found a $\varepsilon >0$ such that the sequence does not converge (meaning that $|x_n - a | \geq \epsilon$) then indeed the sequence does not have a limit.

Comment: Did OP really prove that, no matter what $a$ is chosen, there is an $x_n$ further than $1$ from $a$? [I think that would be straightforward from the formulas for $a_n$ depending on parity of $n$ that he put in post.]

Comment: I don't see how $\frac{\sin(n)}{2^n}$ is periodic. What would be it's period?

Comment: @coffeemath but $a$ is given to equal $3$, do we really need to consider the case of "any" $a$?

Comment: @roman Sorry, I thought you meant a sequence involving periodic terms. As for the convergence part, your proof is correct. Since you are only interested for $a=3$ it is enough what you've done. The case of any $a$ determines just a wider form of limit.

Comment: @coffeemath Since the OP is interested for the value of a supposed limit of $a=3$ he/she does not have to check for all the cases of limits $a \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @roman Yes I rushed over without seeing $c=3$ assumption.

Comment: @Rebellos Yes, I rushed over not seeing $a=3$ assumption.